# Fixed table header with ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Table is not sorting when table contents are refreshed using ajax in html. can any one suggest a best method to sort and fix table header with refreshing table content. Its urgent please replay as soon as possible , Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us some of the code? It'll be difficult to diagnose without that.

Comment: Try to use <thead> and <tbody> sections, Just update ajax response in tBody section

Comment: can you please show some code. I didn't gate sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thead for table header and call data in tbody.

Use this ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'example.xml',           // url from where you want to get data
        data: xml,                  // data form
        success: function (data) {
            $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+data+'</td></tr>')'
        }
    });
```

You may got html structure something like this after ajax call.

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's this comment or answer?

Comment: Actually div is reloading  using ajax , inside the div table contents are not sorting.